# PHP - Force function parameter to integer

Tags: php, function, parameters

In PHP you can do the following thing:

```
class Something {// bla bla}

function functionName(Something $object) {
    // Do stuff here  ^^^^^^^^^
}
```

This ensures that function received an instance of Something class.

My problem is that I want to enforce to a basic type.

```
function functionName(integer $someInt) {
    // Do stuff here  ^^^^^^^
}
functionName(5);
```

This says that $someInt is "not an instance of integer, integer given" (with my PHP version below 7.0). How can you enforce to a basic type?

Comment: there's no integer keyword in php

Comment: you can simply add `$someInt = (int)$someInt;` on the first line of your function. this way you will always get an integer argument format.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do this for [scalar types](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) see the manual:

And a quote from there:

> Type hints **cannot be used with scalar types such as int or string**. Resources and Traits are not allowed either.

But you will be able to to this with PHP 7: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5

Comment: @jeroen Thanks!, was just going to add it with a quote :D

Comment: @Rizier123 Sounds promising that PHP 7 will support that. I've asked multiple times for that feature, but always got an answer like `you don't need to typehint scalar types if you understand dynamically typed languages`.. Hihi, seems I got it right! :D

Comment: @hek2mgl yeah there was a few attempts/proposal for this, but I think it will get added. (Didn't know about the `SPlInt` also an interesting way ;D)

Comment: Yeah, interesting. More interesting it would be if PHP would support a magic method `__toInt()` like `__toString()`. There is also an RFC for that.

Answer (score 7):

You can't typehint scalar types in PHP. The only chance is to use a wrapper type. The SPL library ships with [`SplInt`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splint.php) for that purpose.

Update: Looks like PHP 7 offers that feature. Sigh, times changed :)