# It is possible to require more than one type of function param?

Tags: php

I have following PHP code:

```
protected $number;

public function setIntNumber( int $number ) { /* some operations */ }
public function setFloatNumber( float $number ) { /* the same operations */ }
```

`$number` can store only int or float values. I would like to merge this two functions into one, but the main condition is that other programmer cannot enter other param than int or float. I need something like that:

```
public function setNumber( (int|float) $number ) { /* operations */ }
```

It is possible to do it **EXACTLY** in declaration of my function?

Comment: I ask out of curiosity :)

Comment: Are we talking about `PHP-7`? Because in earlier PHP versions you can't do scalar type hinting.

Comment: PHP in version not higher that 5.5

Comment: Well then I think your first problem is that you can't do type hinting for scalar types (Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29169252/3933332)

Comment: Your question does not have to be asked, what you ask for is not required. Just leave away the type hinting and you can hand over whatever parameter you want. Then, inside the function, you can test for the argument type, if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php):

> Type hints cannot be used with scalar types such as **int** or string.
>   Resources and Traits are not allowed either.

Even if you could use these types, you can't use *multiple* types anyway. The best thing you can do is to check the values at the top of your method and throw an exception.